# Updating gcc on Google Compute Engine Debian 9.13 VM to make R packages install properly

Tags: r, gcc, debian, google-compute-engine

I am on a VM spun up by Google Compute Engine, running Debian 9.13. I am having problems installing R packages to both R 3.3.3 and R 4.0.1, with `non-zero exit status` preventing successful install. One of the remedies from other answers here and in RStudio Community is to make sure `gcc` is updated. So I follow the instructions for Debian 9.13 and do:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

... which tells me that `build-essential is already the newest version (12.3).` But when I check the `gcc` version it shows me a very old version:

```
User@myvm-1:/usr/local/ $ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Because this is on a GCE VM, I am wondering if there is a simpler way to update the compiler -- or if there is a completely different way to help get my R packages to install without the `non-zero exit status` error. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's back off a little here.  You choose Debian 9.13, or the 13th and final version of "oldstable" (see https://www.debian.org/News/2020/20200718).

If you want newer tools, maybe you should start with Debian 10 aka "stable"?  (I happen to be a strong believer in using Debian "testing" which I use for example as the basis of the official "r-base" Rocker container for R, but that is a different story. You could also use Ubuntu LTS which tends to be newer than Debian stable which is very conservative). Now, even if you stay with Debian stable I think you will get `gcc-7` or `gcc-8`.

Next, we need to see the actual compilation errors to help you.

Lastly, know that Debian has a) a fair number of binary packages for R and b) very good "backported" packages of R itself at CRAN in the directory http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

Comment: Is there an OS or any other GCP you specifically recommend for rocker/r-rmd? That's precisely what sent me down this path. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: To a first approximation it really depends. Debian is very general which is why `rocker/r-base` uses Debian testing. But see several of my [posts and videos](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/code/r4) making the case for easier binary install on Ubuntu.  Personally speaking I would pick the most recent Ubuntu LTS, currently 20.04, or even just the most recent Ubuntu release (currently also 20.04) and update it every six months.